# Can I force Universal Image Loader to cache only internally?

Tags: android, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

Having the cache saved externally(SDcard) would cause it not to be deleted during uninstall. I don't want that to happen, can I edit `UIL` library such that it only saves cache internally(inside app). I'm using `LimitedAgeDiscCache` anyway so it will be deleted in any given time.

If yes, should I alter `getOwnCacheDirectory` method from `StorageUtils.class`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)'s method, diskCache(), to set your DiskCache for universal image loader. And this customized disk cache could prefer internal cache.

And we can create internal storage by public method from Universal-Image-Loader, its StorageUtils.

For example,

```
// false to indicator we don't prefer external storage.
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context, false); 
// to avoid exception, we still prepare a default one as universal image loader
File reserveCacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);

long cacheMaxSize = 15 * 1024 * 1024; // 15 MB

DiskCache diskCache;
try {
    diskCache = new LruDiscCache(cacheDir, reserveCacheDir, DefaultConfigurationFactory.createFileNameGenerator(), cacheMaxSize, 0);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // if we cannot use LruDiscCache with internal cache, jut use DefaultConfigurationFactory instead
    diskCache = DefaultConfigurationFactory.createDiskCache(context, DefaultConfigurationFactory.createFileNameGenerator(), cacheMaxSize, 0);
}

ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .diskCache(diskCache);
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Hope this could be useful for you.